# Isomorphism between sets of functions

Tags: functions, category-theory

Suppose we have a set $X$ and sets $A_1,...,A_n$. Is there an isomorphism between the set of functions $Y = X \rightarrow (A_1 \times ... \times A_n)$ from $X$ to the cartesian product of the $A_i$, and the cartesian product $Z = (X \rightarrow A_1) \times ... \times (X \rightarrow A_n)$ of the sets of functions $X \rightarrow A_i$ from $X$ to the $A_i$?

I think this is the case: given $f \in Y$ we can define $t \in Z$ by $\pi_i(f(x)) = \pi_i(t)(x)$ (where $\pi_i$ is the projection to the i-th component of the tuple), and vice versa. But I don't know if there is anything I am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is indeed a natural bijection between the collection of functions from a given set $X$ to a cartesian product $\prod A_i$, and the cartesian product $\prod A_i^X$ (where for sets $A$ and $B$, the set $B^A$ represents the set of all functions $f\colon A\to B$).

This is an instance of the **universal property of the product** (and the fact that the cartesian product of sets corresponds to the [categorical product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)) for the category $\mathsf{Set}$).

Namely, the cartesian product $\prod A_i$ of a family of sets $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$, together with the coordinate projections, can be characterized up to unique bijection by the following properties:

1. It "comes" equipped with a family of functions $\pi_j\colon \prod A_i\to A_j$ for each $j\in I$; and
2. For every set $X$, and every family of functions $f_j\colon X\to A_j$ for each $j\in J$, there exists a unique function $f\colon X\to \prod A_i$ such that for each $j\in I$, $f_j = \pi_j\circ f$.

Comment: The product is not characterized up to *unique* bijection unless you demand that the projections belong to the data and the bijection is compatible with them. But right now you only postulate their existence in 1.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Fair point.